# Convert horizontal wind movement of a swaying tree into vertical movement under the tree

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, potential-energy

How to efficiently convert the horizontal wind movement of a swaying tree into vertical movement under the tree? One way I can imagine is by tying a rope to a point in the ground some distance from the tree and to the top of the tree. The farther away from the tree, the more efficient will be the conversion. However if the tree sways towards the none-moving ground point then the mechanism won't work. Any remedy to that or other ideas, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I get your question right: The tree is swaying in the wind as an elastic beam or like a leaf spring, driven by turbulent gusts. You intend to convert this swaying motion into vertical motion and to possibly harvest some energy out of this, right? Funny idea.

This could look like (is this your idea with tying a rope to it?)
[image]

i.e. we tie a rope to the tree, let it go over some roll to convert its motion into a vertical direction and then have a mass hanging at the end that we would expect to oscillate up and down. To not be dependent on a particular wind direction we can do this in two orthogonal axes.

Alternatively we could connect an L-shaped beam to the tree with bearings at the red marked points:
[image]
Edit: You have an L-shaped beam that revolves around the pivot at B and with a pivot at A is connected to another beam that is somehow attached to the tree.

No idea how efficient this would be.

Comment: The idea of your approach no. 1 is strikingly down-to-earth practical because of its simple mechanism and does not call for extra moving parts. You correctly guessed, and well summarized my intentions. I would like to use wind gusts and sail-spring property of a tree to move a piston of a water pump. I do not understand your approach no. 2 of the L letter. Are both red points pivots, or sort of hinges? Or is it only the upper, and the lower is fixed at right angle? BTW. I like your drawings :-)

Comment: I've edited the drawing and added a little bit of explanation. If (or shall I say when?) you try any of this or some suggestions that somebody else might make, I'd really be interested in the results, power output for example.